# How to display the subtotal of each of the same category using php

Tags: php

```
$stmt = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

if($stmt === false) {
  die( print_r( mysqli_errors(), true) );
}

$category1 = 0;
$category2 = 0;
$category3 = 0;
$category4 = 0;
$category5 = 0;
$category6 = 0;
$category7 = 0;
$category8 = 0;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt)) {

   if(strcasecmp($row['fruit_name'], 'apple') == 0) {
         $category1++;
   }
   if(strcasecmp($row['fruit_name'], 'banana') == 0) {
         $category2++;
   }
   if(strcasecmp($row['fruit_name'], 'cherry') == 0) {
         $category3++;
   }   
   if(strcasecmp($row['fruit_name'], 'dragon fruit') == 0) {
         $category4++;
   } 
   if(strcasecmp($row['fruit_name'], 'eastern hawthorn') == 0) {
         $category5++;
   } 
   if(strcasecmp($row['fruit_name'], 'finger lime') == 0) {
         $category6++;
   } 

   $sum = $row['total_fruit'] + $sum;

   $output .= '<tr>
             <td>' . $row['fruit_name'] . '</td>
             <td align=center>' .$row['total_fruit'] . '</td>
            </tr>';       
}
$output .= '<tr><td>$sum</td></tr></table>';

echo $output;
```

How to display the subtotal of each of the same category of ['fruit_name'] on the last row in the same category. I have total of 6 categories of fruits.
How to display the subtotal of each of the same category of ['fruit_name'] on the last row in the same category. I have total of 6 categories of fruits.

```
fruit_name | total_fruit
Apple      |      1
Apple      |      1
Apple      |      1
Subtotal   |      3
Banana     |      1
Banana     |      1
Banana     |      1
Subtotal   |      3
Total      |      6
```

Comment: instead of `if else` just take an array and assign values to it. and then use `array_count_values()` to get details:-http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php   . Check here:- https://eval.in/665351

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this changed loop, but it will work only if for example all the apples are one after another:

```
$current = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt)) {
    $last = false;

   if(strcasecmp($row['fruit_name'], 'apple') == 0) {
         $category1++;
         if($current > 0 && $current != 1) {
            $output .= '<tr>
             <td>Subtotal</td>
             <td align=center>' .$category{$current} . '</td>
            </tr>';
            $current = 1;
         }
   }
   if(strcasecmp($row['fruit_name'], 'banana') == 0) {
         $category2++;
         if($current > 0 && $current != 2) {
            $output .= '<tr>
             <td>Subtotal</td>
             <td align=center>' .$category{$current} . '</td>
            </tr>';
            $current = 2;
         }
   }
   if(strcasecmp($row['fruit_name'], 'cherry') == 0) {
         $category3++;
         if($current > 0 && $current != 3) {
            $output .= '<tr>
             <td>Subtotal</td>
             <td align=center>' .$category{$current} . '</td>
            </tr>';
            $current = 3;
         }
   }
   if(strcasecmp($row['fruit_name'], 'dragon fruit') == 0) {
         $category4++;
         if($current > 0 && $current != 4) {
            $output .= '<tr>
             <td>Subtotal</td>
             <td align=center>' .$category{$current} . '</td>
            </tr>';
            $current = 4;
         }
   }
   if(strcasecmp($row['fruit_name'], 'eastern hawthorn') == 0) {
         $category5++;
         if($current > 0 && $current != 5) {
            $output .= '<tr>
             <td>Subtotal</td>
             <td align=center>' .$category{$current} . '</td>
            </tr>';
            $current = 5;
         }
   }
   if(strcasecmp($row['fruit_name'], 'finger lime') == 0) {
         $category6++;
         if($current > 0 && $current != 6) {
            $output .= '<tr>
             <td>Subtotal</td>
             <td align=center>' .$category{$current} . '</td>
            </tr>';
            $current = 6;
         }
   }

   $sum = $row['total_fruit'] + $sum;

   $output .= '<tr>
             <td>' . $row['fruit_name'] . '</td>
             <td align=center>' .$row['total_fruit'] . '</td>
            </tr>';
}
$output .= '<tr><td>$sum</td></tr></table>';

echo $output;
```